# Runinng iostat,mpstat,vmstat along with executable

Tags: shell

## !/bin/sh

```
echo "Running IOSTAT"
iostat 2
echo "Running MPSTAT"
mpstat -P ALL 2
echo "Running VMSTAT"
vmstat 2
echo "Running executable"
./a.out 2 1024
echo "Done"
```

I wanted to test the performance of the executable that is running. I have written a script. Its only displaying the iostat and not the remaining 3. How to run all the 4 parallely ?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an ampersand '&' at the end of each command. This launches the executable in the background.  Example:

`mpstat -P ALL 2 &`

Comment: I have put the & for all and  none of them ae stopping with ctrl + C / Q /Z/D . And system got hanged.

Comment: Use `kill` command with `-5` to stop the background process using its PID.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to run the commands in the background and redirect their IO to files for later review.

A shell will execute a command until that command completes and returns providing an exit code for further commands to act upon.

You run a command in the background using `&`.

You can redirect both stdout and stderr to a file using `>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`

Lastly you need to kill the running iostat, mpstat, and vmstat using job control. Each spawned background process can be accessed using `%` and a number. Thus you can kill the first background job using `kill %1`

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Running IOSTAT"
iostat 2 >iostat-stdout.txt 2>iostat-stderr.txt &
echo "Running MPSTAT"
mpstat -P ALL 2 >mpstat-stdout.txt 2>mpstat-stderr.txt &
echo "Running VMSTAT"
vmstat 2 >vmstat-stdout.txt 2>vmstat-stderr.txt &
echo "Running executable"
./a.out 2 1024
echo "Done"
kill %1
kill %2
kill %3
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is only on the IOSTAT

Comment: Now I could not see the .txt files

Comment: If your system is fast enough iostat, mpstat, and vmstat may not have started by the time your application starts and finishes. Thus the kill signal is sent before they have a chance to create any files. This script only works if "./a.out" is a long running job.